# How do I make the days of the month dynamic using moment.js

Tags: node.js, momentjs, ejs

I'm creating a calendar app using node.js and ejs. I made the months and years dynamic. I can't figure out how to make the days of the month dynamic so they keep up with each month. I'm trying to use moment.js for the days of the week.

This is what my app looks like right now.
[image]

When I press next or previous the months and years change, but the days stay static. I need help with two things how do I loop through ul of the days so I don't have to write 31 ul and li's for each day of the month and how do I make sure the days keep up with each month so they start on the right day.

Here is my code for the days of the week, I used CSS to make them a line in the position they're in right now.

```
<ul class="days">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
and so on...
```

How do I loop through these so I have 31 days and then how do I use moment.js to display the day? Thank You, guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of days in a month with *[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/days-in-month/)* `daysInMonth()` function.

```
function getDaysInMonth (date) {
  return moment(date).daysInMonth()
}
var monthDays = getDaysInMonth(date)
```

And you can loop in your *[ejs](https://ejs.co/#docs)* template like you would do in javascript:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < monthDays; i++) { %>
  <li><%= monthDays[i] %></li>
<% } %>
```